# Wrong time difference value in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to add a countdown and I need to calculate the remaining time in millisecond.

Basically I have a button that user can press 24 hours after the last press.

I have

```
last_press
# => Mon, 10 Jan 2022 10:31:25.000000000 UTC +00:00
```

And the time difference.
I add 1 day to the last press and I remove the current time

```
Time.now
# => 2022-01-10 11:50:59 +0100

time_diff = last_press + 1.day - Time.now
```

If I parse the result is

```
Time.at(time_diff.to_i.abs).utc.strftime "%H:%M:%S"
# => "00:09:24"
```

The issue is that `time_diff` is a float

```
time_diff = last_meditation + 1.day - Time.now
# => 85180.960988
```

Basically the calculation is wrong... and I cannot understand why.

Comment: The calculation seems fine. 85180 seconds is roughly 24 hours. The rendering seems fine too: `Time.at(85180.960988.to_i.abs).utc.strftime "%H:%M:%S" # => "23:39:40"`

Comment: When you subtract two `Time` objects , Ruby returns the different between the two times in (fractional) seconds. As the difference between your two timestamps is about 20 minutes, you the return value is `1 day - 20 minutes`, or specifically `24*60*60 - 1220 = 85180` (with 1220 being the approximate difference in seconds between your two timestamps).

Comment: To get milliseconds, just multiply the result by 1000 (and maybe `.round` it)

Comment: To work accurately with relative time use [DateTime.advance](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-advance) instead of an ActiveSupport::Duration. `last_meditation.advance(days: 1)` or `last_meditation.advance(hours: 24)`.  `1.day` gives you an ActiveSupport duration that represents 86400 seconds. While you naively might think thats the same thing as a day stuff like Daylight Savings Time, leap seconds and rounding errors are waiting right around the bend to give you a very bad time.

Comment: @max `DateTime@#advance` does NOT take DST or leapseconds into account. However, it still can produce more correct (or rather expected) results as it only explicitly changes the requested "fields" (i.e. increase the day by one but keep the hours, minute, and second untouched) rather than performing time calculations which might produce unexpected results depending on the local timezone.

Comment: @HolgerJust I stand corrected.